# Docker Build within Azure YAML Pipeline not copying files

Tags: azure, docker, copy

I am trying to build and publish a Docker Container from within a YAML Pipeline, and the pipeline is calling the docker build like this:

```
  - task: Docker@2
displayName: 'Build Docker Image'
inputs:
  containerRegistry: 'MyContainerRegistrySandpit'
  repository: 'MyTestRepo'
  command: 'build'
  Dockerfile: '**/Dockerfile'
  arguments: '--no-cache --build-arg DockerFiles=$(DockerFiles) --build-arg APIFiles=$(APIFiles)'
```

```
  - task: Docker@2
    displayName: 'Push Docker container'
    inputs:
      containerRegistry: 'MyContainerRegistrySandpit'
      repository: 'MyTestRepo'
      command: 'push'
```

That's all working as expected.

The issue is when I try to copy the files in the Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0

ARG APIFiles
ARG DockerFiles

RUN echo "Docker Files Path set to: $DockerFiles" 
COPY $DockerFiles/ /usr/DockerFiles

RUN echo "API Path set to: $APIFiles"
COPY $APIFiles/ /usr/app
```

I am setting those variables in my pipeline, and the output is this:

```
Step 4/20 : RUN echo "Docker Files Path set to: $DockerFiles"
 ---> Running in c64ce8687e7b
Docker Files Path set to: /home/vsts/work/1/a/drop/DockerFiles
Removing intermediate container c64ce8687e7b
 ---> f645841189b2
Step 5/20 : COPY $DockerFiles/ /usr/DockerFiles
COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat home/vsts/work/1/a/drop/DockerFiles/: file does not exist
##[error]COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat home/vsts/work/1/a/drop/DockerFiles/: file does not exist
##[error]The process '/usr/bin/docker' failed with exit code 1
```

As a sanity check, I have a PS script to output the files that the Build Agent can see:

```
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
/usr/bin/pwsh -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -Command . '/home/vsts/work/_temp/73418598-90b3-4f6d-abeb-0f944dbf1c08.ps1'
/home/vsts/work/1/a/drop/DockerFiles Contents:
bytecode.cvd
daily.cvd
entry-point.sh
main.cvd
```

No matter what I do, I can't get my files to copy accross. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else having a similar issue, I found the answer.

Turns out that there is a scope in which the Dockerbuild context runs and can copy files. The context - in my case - is the folder in which the Dockerfile was executed, so it could not reach outside of the folder to get the files, even though they existed.

See here for more details: https://docs.docker.com/build/building/context/

Comment: This one helped me set the context to a parent path by simply using `context: ../../`